# An Android service is not recognized as a registered service although it is

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

I created a `NetworkSchedulerService` which extends `JobService` using Kotlin.
Of course I registered it in the manifest, but for some reason AndroidStudio marks it with warning:

```
the <service> project.services.network.NetworkSchedulerService is not registered in the manifest
```

When I run the app, it crashes (no surprises) with the error:

```
09-18 03:18:56.271 22289-22289/project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: project, PID: 22289
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{project/project.ui.home.HomeScreenActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{projectt/project.services.network.NetworkSchedulerService}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Mt manifest registration:

```
    <service
        android:name="services.network.NetworkSchedulerService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

How I call it (from the `onCreate()` of the main activity):

```
fun scheduleJob() {
        val myJob = JobInfo.Builder(0, ComponentName(this, NetworkSchedulerService::class.java))
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .setMinimumLatency(1000)
                .setOverrideDeadline(2000)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .build()

        val jobScheduler = getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
        jobScheduler.schedule(myJob)
}
```

My `NetworkSchedulerService` class:

```
open class NetworkSchedulerService : JobService(), ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener {

    private val TAG = NetworkSchedulerService::class.java.simpleName
    private lateinit var mConnectivityReceiver: ConnectivityReceiver

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate")
        mConnectivityReceiver = ConnectivityReceiver(this)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand")
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStopJob $mConnectivityReceiver")
        unregisterReceiver(mConnectivityReceiver)
        return true
    }

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartJob $mConnectivityReceiver")
        registerReceiver(mConnectivityReceiver, IntentFilter(CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))
        return true
    }

    override fun onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected: Boolean) {
        val message = if (isConnected) "Good! Connected to Internet" else "Sorry! Not connected to internet"
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

I tried to open the NetworkSchedulerService class (since it's static and final by default), tried to clean the project and so many other things.
Can anyone assist, please?

Comment: Do you have to give the service it's full name (including the package) in the manifest?

Comment: @DavidChristopherReynolds otherwise it won't recognize the class

Answer (score 1):

Well, after literally an entire day that I'm on it with no success (before posting this question), I found the problem!
I was missing

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

in the manifest. found it by accident :)

Comment: how come this is a solution for the problem? this makes no sense at all!